# Does Blender compute all previous modifiers to a Geometry Nodes each time a value is changed in the GN?

Tags: geometry-nodes, performance

Does Blender compute all previous modifiers to a Geometry Nodes each time a value is changed in the GN?

-I mean, for example, if I have a big mesh and I want to reduce its vertices with a decimate modifier before the GN. Does Blender compute that modifier each time I change a value in the GN?

-And another question: If I add just two nodes, a merge by distance and then a set position. Each time I made a change in the set position does it also compute the merge by distance? Thanks

Thanks!

Comment: Merge by distance doesn't do the same as decimate. So if one performs and other doesn't, I think that kind of helps to determine which performs better.

Comment: Thank you Marynas, I undestand so I updated the question. But the main point is if it computes all modifiers previous to a GN each time a value is changed in the GN. Thanks!